# Codility test result unclear

Tags: c#

I solved [this](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/) codility test with the following code:

```
private static int lesson2_1(int[] A) {
        if (!Isvalid(A))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        List<int> d = A.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in d)
        {
            var q = from one in A where one == item select one;
            if (q.Count() == 1)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }

        return -1;
}

 private static bool Isvalid(int[] a)
    {
        if (a.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

These are the results:

[image]

I do not know how to approach this, since I have not learned yet about complexity. Can someone please guide me to the right approach to this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: They have an examples and articles about complexity of particular algorithms, try to spend some time looking at them

Comment: Roughly, complexity means "if I have O(N) complexity, and I process 1000 elements in time T, then i should process 2000 elements in roughly time 2T, if I have O(N-squared) complexity, and I move from 1000 to 2000 elements, it will take 4T (since 2 squared is 4). Other popular "Big O" values are O(1) (increasing the number of items does not noticeably increase processing time) and O(N*log(N)) - the complexity of an efficient sort or tree traversal algorithm. Generally, N-squared is bad (anything above that is really bad)). There are tons of blog posts addressing this, enjoy your reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice - don't reinvent the wheel. .Net has a lot built into it. Chances are unless you have specialist requirements Microsoft will be able to implement it better than you. The following gets a 100% score:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        return A.GroupBy(a => a).First(a => a.Count() %2 == 1).Key;
    }
}
```

There are a few issues with your solution.

1) You aren't following the test spec. It states

> all but one of the values in A occur an even number of times.

That means that the number you are looking for could occur, 3,5,7,etc. times - you are just checking for 1.

2) The time complexity of your solution is poor. You are looping through every item and doing a search for each item within every loop. This isn't necessary if you think about it. You will have to go through every item in the list but if you process it as you go along you effectively only have to go through each item once and then the buckets of each item once.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and helpfull answer!